Asymmetric graph with with increasing depth of asymmetry
Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph. Define the depth of asymmetry as $|V| - d$, where $d$ is the rank of the largest non-trivial partial automorphism of a graph $G$. Can we find a construction such that $d$ will increase?
I have been trying to generalize the graph on the picture, which prohibits rotational symmetry as well as inverse symmetry by having three different parts. It is trivial to see that the degree will have to increase for each vertex to obtain bigger $d$. Moreover, the symmetric difference of pairs of vertices will have to increase to avoid having small $d$.
1: 
